# Как вытащить массив с клоужера?

Tags: swift, swift4

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь освоить decodablе. После парсинга мне надо записать данные в массив и отображать их в tableView. Для этого я for(ом) добавляю значения в массив, но за телом функции массив остается пустым. Как правильно записать данные в этом случае? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо изображения, пожалуйста добавьте ваш код текстом

Comment: Это асинхронный запрос, результат которого появится в какой-то неопределенный момент в будущем. Соответственно, нужен механизм оповещения, что код выполнился и данные готовы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Ваш объект `UITableView` выводит данные на основе `walksArray`, то просто перерисуйте его после инициализации `walksArray`. Добавьте следующий код после `print(self.walksArray.count)`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()            
}
```

Проверять `walksArray` сразу после вызова `downloadsWalks` смысла нет, потому что данная функция завершается, не дожидаясь вызова замыкания, в котором Вы инициализируете `walksArray`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо